# Question classification

Tags: deep-learning, multiclass-classification, multilabel-classification, nlp

I have 10 classes and 10-15 questions in each class .
Given a new question, I want to find the class to which the question is most similar?

Answer (score 0):

This is called **sequence classification**. An approach to attack this problem is to deploy an LSTM-RNN. The key is the preprocessing of the dataset; how you encode a written question into appropriate input for the network.

The answer to this is called **word embedding** and detailed instructions of how to implement it can be found in this [tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/sequence-classification-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/), hope it helps :)

Comment: But my only concern is that as the data is very less, there will be overfitting. So is it actually feasible?

Comment: you can always generate **synthetic** data to train your algorithm